# MySql Results Coming in but not showing

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get my applications in a list them so they can be approved or denied. I've done MANY selected and displays before but for some reason this one isn't working. It displays the table... eg: Username, Who are you? etc. But it doesn't show the $applicationRow['Username'] and such. I have ran the query through a mysql editor and it worked fine so I know its not that. It is going into the while loop because it showing the table... But why isnt it showing the results???

```
$applicationQuery = "SELECT tblMembers.Username, tblMembers.Bio, tblApplications.WhyJoin, tblApplications.Games, tblApplications.FoundBy, tblApplications.Joke
                                FROM tblApplications
                                INNER JOIN tblMembers ON tblMembers.ID = tblApplications.MemberID
                                WHERE Approved=0";
        echo $applicationQuery;
        $applicationResults = mysql_query($applicationQuery) or die(mysql_error());

        while($applicationRow = mysql_fetch_row($applicationResults))
        {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "</tr><td>Username:</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['Username']."</tr>";
            echo "</tr><td>Who are you?</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['Bio']."</tr>";
            echo "</tr><td>What games do you play?</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['Games']."</tr>";
            echo "</tr><td>How did you find us?</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['FoundBy']."</tr>";
            echo "</tr><td>Why do you want to join?</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['WhyJoin']."</tr>";
            echo "</tr><td>Tell us a joke:</td><td></td>".$applicationRow['Joke']."</tr>";
            echo "</table><hr/>";
        }
```

Comment: Also make sure you correct your HTML markup, opening table row tags should be ```<tr>``` and your values should be inside the table cell, like ```<td>content</td>```.

Comment: Taking the minimal time to read the manual would solve problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_row()` returns a numerical array.

Try `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead. This will return an associative array, which it appears is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to mysql_fetch_array as thats what I normally use. I knew it would be something stupid like that :D

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$applicationQuery = "SELECT tblMembers.Username, tblMembers.Bio, tblApplications.WhyJoin, tblApplications.Games, tblApplications.FoundBy, tblApplications.Joke
                                FROM tblApplications
                                INNER JOIN tblMembers ON tblMembers.ID = tblApplications.MemberID
                                WHERE Approved=0";
```

to

```
$applicationQuery = "SELECT tblMembers.Username as Username, tblMembers.Bio as Bio, tblApplications.WhyJoin as WhyJoin, tblApplications.Games as Games, tblApplications.FoundBy as FoundBy, tblApplications.Joke ad Joke
                                FROM tblApplications
                                INNER JOIN tblMembers ON tblMembers.ID = tblApplications.MemberID
                                WHERE Approved=0";
```

as your column aliases are not matching when you are fetching in while loop

and use `mysql_fetch_Array` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`